# Angular - reference child component dynamically

Tags: angular

Giving the following structure:

root:

```
<parent>
    <child>1st child content</child>
    <child>2nd child content</child>
</parent>
```

parent.html:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="children[currentChildIndex]"></ng-container><br/>
```

parent.ts:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ContentChildren(ChildComponent, { read: TemplateRef })
  set childrenQueryList(val: QueryList<ChildComponent>) {
    this.children = val.toArray();
  }
  children;
  currentChildIndex = 0
```

child.html:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

child.ts:

```
public foo() {
    alert(`foo`)
  }
```

when I'm trying to call a child method from the parent like:

```
this.children[0].foo()
```

I'm getting

```
Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined
```

and, of course, the children aren't showing.

[Not working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dpcuqh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.html)

Comment: your demo link does not seem to have any parent child components

Comment: Fixed. Thank you

Comment: @ContentChildren(ChildComponent, { read: TemplateRef }), you should not read TemplateRef; try remove it and also in html file, using ngComponentOutlet

Comment: @ABOS Thanks but it didn't work. Only after looking into angular materials impl. I figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you have to use ng-template and then show the **template** in the view.

Change child.html to have a template:

```
<ng-template><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>
```

in child.ts add:

```
@ViewChild(TemplateRef) content: TemplateRef<any>;
```

in parent.html change to:

```
*ngTemplateOutlet="children[currentChildIndex].content"
```